# Does zbar supports ipod touch?

Tags: iphone, barcode, ipod-touch

I am working on an barcode reader app which currently uses zbar sdk, i works like magic on iphone 4G  but does it also works with ipod touch????? 
   if it does'nt then is that any other api which supports barcode reader in ipod touch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. For QR codes its quite fast. But for UPC, you may have to be a bit specific about the distance from where you are scanning though(scan from 30cms). Read [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/forums/forum/1072195/topic/3849436) for further info.

Comment: As per their site, it works with those device which have "auto-focus" functionality. So there you go. It Does.

Comment: thanks i just want zbar to work with iphone 4g and ipod touch, if it works with both thats great,

Comment: @Aadil if that solves your query you should consider upvoting and accepting the answer.. :)

Comment: @idev i still confused about ipod touch because it's camera does not hav auto focus so might not work with zbar